# How do I sum only the positive numbers in a stream?

Tags: java

I have list values in stream while iterating I need to check if that value is negative or not if negative return zero or else retrun same value

Below is my code

```
              {
                       Inventory .stream().
                       map.(inventory.value).sum;
                 }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  You show sum in your code, but talk about checking a value.  What value?  The sum value?  Or the individual values?

Comment: @nycynik : individual value which is there in
 stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `Math.min` for this. You'll have to map over them as integers, presumably:

```
Inventory.stream()
    .mapToInt(it -> Math.min(0, it.value))
    .sum()
```

Comment: Cool, you should probably accept the answer. Accepting answers makes people want to help you more in the future.